# How long does the tourist visa extension process take in Guangzhou, China?

Tags: visas, china, visa-extensions, guangzhou, tourist-visas

I am approaching the end of my second stay of my dual-entry visa in China.

I am in Guangzhou and aware that another option is to pop over to Hong Kong and apply for a new Chinese visa there.

But HK is pricey when you're a on a shoestring hitchhiker's budget with a bank balance getting low. And in any case I would like to know ...

How long does it take to apply for and obtain a plain 30-day extension to a plain tourist visa (type L) here in Guangzhou?

From reading various information on the internet the process has quite a lot of variation around China with Tibet being almost impossible, Beijing being very difficult and demanding, and some small towns being extremely simple.

Yet no threads I can find have information about Guangzhou specifically. Does anyone have experience extending a visa here in the past year or so?

(Yes I have a Temporary Residence Registration Form (临时住宿登记) from my hostel.)

References:

- [China Visa Extension Thread @ Lonely Planet Thorn Tree](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/asia-north-east-asia/china/china-visa-extension-thread?page=58)
- [Visa policy of China / Visa application procedures for foreign nationals (aliens) @ Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_China#Visa_application_procedures_for_foreign_nationals_.28aliens.29)
- [China / Types of visas @ Wikivoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/China#Types_of_visas)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It takes **7 working days**, so normally 9 days due to weekends.

It costs **¥160 `CNY`**. The passport photo needed is special, with a blue background. You can get a set for ¥33 `CNY` in the building.

Applying with **only one day left** of your current visit is **not a problem**!

The office is **very efficient**, and waiting times are short, despite the large number of people.

You are given an official receipt which includes a copy of the important parts of your passport which I'm told will be acceptable as a travel document in the meantime. A friend here from Russia used this to board a flight once so it should also work for checking in to hotels etc.

Address:

***The Public Security Bureau Exit-Entry Administration Division***, located at 155 Jiefang South Road (解放南路155号) +86 20 8311-5808 (M-F 8:50AM–11:30AM, 2:30PM-5PM.)