# Cheapest agent in Hong Kong for obtaining a visa for mainland China?

Tags: visas, budget, china, hong-kong, visa-runs

I'm in **Guangzhou** with just a few days left on my tourist visa.

[I intended to apply for a visa extension here tomorrow morning](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52140/how-long-does-the-tourist-visa-extension-process-take-in-guangzhou-china?rq=1) (Monday). That should cost about **$31 USD**.

But just found out a travel buddy just moved into a flat in **Hong Kong**.

So I have another option of going to visit him (no visa required for me) and crashing at his place for a few days while I get a new Chinese visa there.

Now, only HK residents can apply for a visa directly in HK and the rest of us are obliged to use an agency.

I'm struggling to find what would be about the lowest price an agent currently charges for this in Hong Kong. I won't need the rush service and it will just be for a single-entry 30-day "L" tourist visa. (Though the price for a dual-entry visa would be good to know too.)

As well as the price I'd like to know how many days it takes so I can tell me friend how long I'd be in the way for (-:

So far I found a price of **$750 HKD (about $100 USD)** but that's for a rush visa.

Comment: I think renewal = new visa. I think you can't extend a mainland visa in HK. I can't think of a third interpretation. $450 HKD is roughly double the price for an extension on the mainland. But not terrible if they tell me I have too few days left on my visa to get an extension here or something like that ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$350 HK for a 4 working day one. I did this last week, Monday afternoon to Thursday noon. 2 entries is 100 more.

The agency I used is [FBT](http://www.fbt-chinavisa.com.hk/), the standard price is $450, but you can print out a $100 discount coupon from their website and bring it along when you pick up the visa and pay.

I was in China for 60 days last year, for this reason they said a new visa may be refused, but in my case wasn't. It may be helpful if you have a second passport.

Comment: That does indeed look the cheapest. In the end I was able to apply for an extension here in Guangzhou even with only one day left for a lower price. But it takes nine days and there was no possibility of getting two more entries. But now we have the answer for all who might Google the question (-: